# Raise event of customized control from class itself

Tags: c#, events

I have a custom `TabPage` class:

```
class CustomTabPage : TabPage
{
    TextBox tbCode = new TextBox();

    public CustomTabPage()
    {

    }

    public CustomTabPage(string title)
    {
        tbCode.Multiline = true;
        tbCode.Size = this.Size;  
    }        

    //Something like this...
    private void OnThisControlSizeChanged()
    {
        tbCode.Size = this.Size;
    }
}
```

What I need for this class is to raise the `OnSizeChanged` event of the `TabPage` control when I resize it from where I create the control. The reason for this is when I resize the `TabPage` control, I want to adapt the `TextBox` size accordingly so that they stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CustomTabPage : TabPage
{
    TextBox tbCode = new TextBox();
    public CustomTabPage()
    {
        SizeChanged += CustomTabPage_SizeChanged;
    }

    void CustomTabPage_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnThisControlSizeChanged();
    }

    public CustomTabPage(string title)
    {
        tbCode.Multiline = true;
        tbCode.Size = this.Size;
    }

    private void OnThisControlSizeChanged()
    {
        tbCode.Size = this.Size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.OnSizeChanged(new EventArgs());
```